# Xcode: Playground execution failed:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode10

Playground execution failed:

[image]

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14eee).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14eee)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000014eee
    frame #1: 0x0000000123c284b2 PlaygroundLogger`playground_logger_initialize + 18
    frame #2: 0x00000001235ba23d $__lldb_expr2`main at playground1-901e96..swift:8
    frame #3: 0x000000010dadc5f0 MyPlayground`linkResources + 304
    frame #4: 0x000000010f71262c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #5: 0x000000010f711de0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    frame #6: 0x000000010f70c654 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    frame #7: 0x000000010f70be11 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    frame #8: 0x00000001173191dd GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #9: 0x000000011371281d UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
    frame #10: 0x000000010dadc6bd MyPlayground`main + 205
    frame #11: 0x0000000110e5a575 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Try restarting playground, sometimes this will fix it :D

Comment: First, you should post code as _text_, not as _screenshot_. In your special case, I would restart Xcode and/or the whole computer, it seems to be a bug in Xcode.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Restarting the Xcode and the system doesn't seems helping. Getting the same error. Can you help?

Comment: what versions of Xcode?

Comment: I using version 10.1 of Xcode.

Comment: Very strange. Pleas try `import Foundation` instead of `import UIKit`.

Answer (score 3):

I gone through couple of different ways to close and restart the program and it finally worked for me, it worked when I try as steps below:

1. File -> Close "Name.playground"
2. File -> Close Playground
3. Quit Xcode
4. Re-open Xcode

Also Inside fileInspector I went to Playground Settings and selected platform as "macOS".

Thanks to everyone for the kind help.

Comment: this worked for me as well. i had the same playground file work on another Xcode on another machine. and only following these 4 steps above afterwards it worked.  I switched to MacOS and then back to iOS since my playground was written for iOS. then it worked.